# Force download file with exec command

Tags: php

I'm using this command line to `gzip` files but I would like not to write the output to the server but only force the download of the `gz` file generated to the browser.

```
$filename = '_backup_fichier.tar.gz';    
exec('find '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images_contenu/source/*.pdf -mtime +0 | xargs tar -czf '.$filename.'', $output, $return);
```

Do you think so it can be done ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suppose you might have missed the fact that you can do this all in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

Comment: Yes i know but is that possible with exec in cmd line ?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru) function.

> The `passthru()` function is similar to the `exec()` function in that it executes a command. This function should be used in place of `exec()` or `system()` when the output from the Unix command is binary data which needs to be passed directly back to the browser.

Example:

```
passthru("find $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/images_contenu/source/*.pdf -mtime +0 | xargs tar -cz");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PharData class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) to collect your files to an archive or use the [buildFromDirectory method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.buildfromdirectory.php).
You need to write the archive to a temp file, deliver it to the client and delete it afterwards to keep your server clean.
Don´t forget to set the correct HTTP response headers.